# Linking a C++ library to a program which has a non-C++ main function

Tags: c++, c, dll, shared-libraries

Given some C++ functions (which use STL), can you use them from a program which has a main function that's not compiled with a C++ compiler? And can you avoid linking that program with the C++ compiler?

I'm aware that the interface must be extern "C" functions and that they shouldn't throw exceptions.

By searching the web, I found many sources hinting that it's not possible, for example:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-libraries.html#C_002b_002b-libraries
  "Therefore, running ld to link a C++ program or library is deemed to fail."
- http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t591272-re-linking-a-c-program-to-a-c-library-which-uses-stl.html
  "a C main program that calls a C++ library is ill-fated from the beginning"

But I also found this:
http://wewantarock.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/working-around-the-static-libstdc-restriction/

I understood that like this: The workaround is to just build a shared library.
You use the C++ compiler to link the shared library, and a shared library is a kind of "program" itself (with startup/teardown functions like DLLMain instead of a normal main function). The program using the shared library doesn't need to know about it being a C++ library.

Did I understand that correctly?

Are there any catches?

Edit 1: I tried it - successfully. I built my shared library with libtool,
and could use it by linking with an ordinary

```
cc c_main_program.o -lmy_cpp_library -o c_main_program
```

**Updated question**, after the successfull experiment: Are there any catches which can
surprise me later (for example on other platforms, or when I use constructors in global variables, ...)

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with using STL internally as long as you export interface are straight c functions using a know calling convention.  Dlls are already built and do not need to have a linker or a compiler invoked to use them.

The issue with the c++ is that the binary format of c++ is implementation dependent so there is no guarantee that source compatible code built with different compilers will be binarlly compatible.  There are separate issue with linking templates as only instantiated concrete version of the template will be included in the library and the compiler has to see the definition of a template to avoid declaring it twice(for most compilers).

c has no such issues c functions have a defined interface and the layout of the data types is also know so dynamic loading from separate compilers has no issue.  But that means that you can only use types and features of c.

for more exhaustive discussion check out [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123850037)

Comment: What about constructors and destructors of objects that are globals?

Comment: first they would be very hard to access in a non c++ program as you would have to extern them and find the symbol some how and then accessing the functions would be almost impossible.  But they could certainly be used by your functions just not to the client.

Comment: So if you linked [this code](https://gist.github.com/3830572) to a C program and called `compute()`, you'd expect it to return the correct value? What would have caused the constructor to be called?

Comment: yesish.  are initialized before dllmain this is from the dllmain doc "If your DLL is linked with the C run-time library (CRT), the entry point provided by the CRT calls the constructors and destructors for global and static C++ objects. Therefore, these restrictions for DllMain also apply to constructors and destructors and any code that is called from them."

Comment: Yeah. Looks like you're correct... I was doing some testing in the background and I was fairly sure that wouldn't work.

Comment: That's a terrible design pattern BTW.

Comment: The binary compatibility shouldn't be a problem with the extern "C" declared interface functions. And I suppose that problem with the constructors/destructors of global issues is not worse than if the main function was in C++, is it?

Comment: _Dlls are already built and do not need to have a linker or a compiler invoked to use them_ - Well, there is the dynamic linker. But that's the same, no matter if the DLL is a C or a C++ library. So you confirmed my hope, that the "client" program doesn't need to know about C++.